# why can't i see material on evee but can in cycles?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, materials, eevee-render-engine, transparency

when i apply material on an object can't see them on render mode on evee. The object becomes transparent also transparent in rendered image but it is working on cycles

Comment: could you post an image of the node setup?

Comment: are you using an amd gpu?